# Saving c# form data

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

```
namespace ZzCleaner
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private CheckedListBox FoldersToClean;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Making directories
        private void ZzCleaner_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)         
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Properties.Settings.Default.FoldersToClear)) 
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.FoldersToClear.Split(',')
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(item =>
                    {
                        var index = this.FoldersToClean.Items.IndexOf(item);
                        var checkbox = this.FoldersToClean.GetItemChecked(item.Count());
                        FoldersToClean.SetItemChecked(index, true);
                    });
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var indices = this.FoldersToClean.CheckedItems.Cast<string>().ToArray();

            Properties.Settings.Default.FoldersToClear = string.Join(",", indices);
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

I've been working on a Windows Forms application, and I ran into an issue with saving data, when closing the program. As from my point of view this should have close and open with correctly ticked checkboxes, because information it's saved in Settings.settings as FoldersToClear, string type, and user.

But it displays as default. In `Form1.cs` [Design] I have edited `CheckedListBox` and put in Images, Videos, and Music words.

So what this should have done, is store ticked boxes with names, and when the program runs again it should be the same as when it closes.

I am new on Stackoverflow, and I could really use some help.

Thanks!

Comment: What is this: `private CheckedListBox FoldersToClean;` and why is it there? Are you sure you're referencing the correct instance of the CheckedListBox you see on screen?

Comment: This assignes CheckListBox from Form.

Comment: A Control added to the Form in the visual Form Designer is added to the `[Form].Designer.cs` file. What is that Field doing there, in the Form code file? Did you try to change something manually, maybe editing the designer file? Other? -- The code you have there, if the correct instance is referenced, should work as expected

Comment: Haven't did anything in Designer itself.

Comment: `private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
 private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox2; 
 private System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox foldersToClean;` But it does say that foldersToClean is never used, but if I put FoldersToClean it says Ambiguity between 'Form1.FoldersToClean'. If I remove `private CheckedListBox FoldersToClean;` and only have it in Designer, it says again that it's never used.

Comment: Again. Since you have *done nothing* in the designer's file, why do you have this Field: `private CheckedListBox FoldersToClean;` in the code file? You're using this (apparently uninitialized) reference to restore the settings. Isn't the Control's instance name actually `foldersToClean` (lower case `f`)? Remove the Field you have added to the code file and use the instance name set in the designer file (the name you have assigned to the CheckedListBox in the visual designer)

Comment: Alright fixed that. But now I have InvalidArgument = Value of '-1' isnot valid for 'index'. Would you know what could be causing this?

Comment: In `var index = [Your CheckedListBox].Items.IndexOf(item);`, the return value is `-1` because the item cannot be found. You probably have renamed the items in the list. Maybe using a different case. `IndexOf()` is case sensitive. Clean the setting

Comment: ```StringBuilder selectedItems = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder indexOf = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (object item in FoldersToClear.Items)
                {
                    
                    selectedItems.Append(item.ToString());
                    selectedItems.Append("," + FoldersToClear.Items.IndexOf(item));

                }
                string selectedItemsString = selectedItems.ToString();``` this shows me everything and Index starts with 0, also Items are all alright in it.